# Rails - cannot destroy a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

while setting up a simple Rails app, I met an issue i never had before: the destroy link will not work.

now, my code is:

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', post, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
```

rather basic, right?

When i click on delete, I get redirected to Show... quite puzzling.

My schema is:

```
t.string   "title"
t.text     "content"
t.string   "category"
t.datetime "created_at", :null => false
t.datetime "updated_at", :null => false
```

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include the jQuery for Rails gem in your Gemfile

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Then you have to run `bundle install` and restart the server. This is because even if you have included in your layout.html.erb the jQuery framework you need the adapter for jQuery to use the unobstrusive scripting.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you have JS enabled, and included in `application.html.haml`.
You can also try `button_to` instead of `link_to`.

Comment: +1, That's right! Because of some reasons(even I don't know) `link_to` can not call destroy method. `button_to` creates a **form** to post data, which apparently works well :-)